# Fastest manner of altering viewcontroller layout on main queue?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have a dataTask making a webservice API call, and in the completion block for that dataTask I use the returned info to build a UIImageView and add it as a subview of the parent UIViewController. I have tried it with two API calls and I would like to know why one causes the UIImageView to be displayed so much slower than the other. Inside of the completion block, the fast call, which takes less than 1 second, is:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        (self.delegate as TBGQRCodeViewController).displayQRCode(receiveAddr, withAmountInBTC:amountBTC)
                        });
```

while the slower call, which takes roughly 13 seconds, is:

```
(self.delegate as TBGQRCodeViewController).displayQRCode(receiveAddr, withAmountInBTC:amountBTC)
```

The first clearly runs on the main queue, but the second one I'm not so sure, since it's running directly in the completion block of the dataTask.

Can someone explain in detail why these two calls of the same function have such markedly different run lengths?

Comment: is `displayQRCode` updates image??

Comment: @codester yes that code creates a QR UIImage, makes a UIImageVIew out of it, and adds it as a subview

Comment: than see my answer for explaination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these calls update the UI ,your first call is on `main thread` which updates your imageView immediately.But your second call directly within `dataTask` completion handler which generally runs on secondary thread run loops so this call

```
(self.delegate as TBGQRCodeViewController).displayQRCode(receiveAddr, withAmountInBTC:amountBTC)
```

run on `secondary thread runloop` so it will not able to update UI. While some other call or some other event reloads the `UIImageView` which display the your computed `image` to display on `UIImageView`.

So as `dataTask` fetch data on secondary thread if your call is directly within completion handler than it is updating your `imageView` on secondary thread which should not be done as all UI must be update on `main thread`.Put your `imageView` updation on `main thread`.

Comment: Could you explain in a little more depth what exactly is happening on the secondary thread runloop? You're answer implies that secondary loop _cannot_ update the UI. Although it takes a long time, it does eventually update the UI, though.

Comment: No but some other event is refreshing the your imageView.Generally this happens when you scroll the contents of view or tableview it tries to again display again content on visible area on that event it your image gets updated.Check also you are not calling displayQrCode again from somewhere else in your code